# Image in content field from selector :before not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, selector, image

I don't know what's going on but the issue is as follows:

I'm trying to load and image in the selector before in the content field like this:

```
.commentlist ul.children:before {
   content: url("images/arrow.png") no-repeat;                                                                                                                                    
   top: 13px;
   left: 11px;
   position: relative; 
 }
```

This works like a charm in webkit browser like Chrome and Safari but not anymore in Firefox, so when i open Firebug and look for my style i can see that the content property is not showing up for that reason is not able to load the content but if i try to put it on the content via Firebug it works! No matter how times refresh, even i try to empty cache, never shows the content style, i miss something? I hope can anyone help me with that issue.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a valid value for the `content` property.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content for the spec.

In particular, the `no-repeat` part is not allowed there.

Of course Firefox tells you that the value is invalid, if you look at its console...